# Python Regex expression is failing - can't figure out why

Tags: python, regex

I'm using:

```
re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9\:\(\) ]+\[[A-Za-z0-9\.]+\:[0-9]+\]$', log)
```

To search a log that looks like this:

```
"Logged at Thursday, March 20, 2014 20:48:03
FileVersion: 3.5.0.44954
ProductVersion: 3.5.0.44954
LogFile: Game.log

Exception Code: FATAL_ERROR
Exception Addr: 
Exception Module: 
Exception Description: FATAL_ERROR, 
Memory in use: 462.7MB
Debug Status: 
Out of Memory: 0

Call Stack Trace:
10) CSystem::FatalError()  [systemwin32.cpp:1267]
9) CFatalError()  [isystem.h:1528]
```

When I test the expression in Sublime Text/Notepad++, it succeeds. But when I run it as shown above in Python, I get nothing back.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to find?

Comment: 10) CSystem::FatalError()  [systemwin32.cpp:1267]

Which is working when I test in ST/N++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use re.M for multiline regex matching.

```
re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9\:\(\) ]+\[[A-Za-z0-9\.]+\:[0-9]+\](?:[\n\r]|\Z)', log, re.M)
                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Also, this regex is checking for `[\n\r]` or `\Z` at the end of regex instead of `$`. FYI, `\Z` means end of input string.

Comment: We only want to find the first occurrence, so multi-line isn't an issue. When we run the query in SublimeText, we get the first line, which is what we're looking for. But when I run this in Python, I just get a NoneType back.

Comment: @JimWeinhart You still need to use the multiline flag since [otherwise `$` is only the end-of-string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) (since in single line mode `\n` is just a normal character). Using `re.M` makes `$` match end-of-line *and* end-of-string

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Sabuj Hassan's answer, the problem is simply that Python is not recognizing the end of the line as a terminal. This is because you are not using [the `MUTILINE` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), `re.M`.

Without this flag Python does not assign any special meaning to `\n` characters and thus `$` will only match the very end of the string. By including the `re.M` flag Python automatically adds terminals before all `\n` characters, thus allowing `$` to match both end-of-line and end-of-string.